# what happened to missing.pattern.plot or mp.plot?

Tags: r

I have the package `mi` installed.

But when I try to run `mp.plot` (as Thomas Leeper does in this tutorial:) I get the following error message:

> mp.plot(mydf)
>   Error in mp.plot(mydf) : could not find function "mp.plot"

On one website this is called `missing.pattern.plot`, but that also does not work:

> missing.pattern.plot(mydf)
>   Error in missing.pattern.plot(mydf) : 
>     could not find function "missing.pattern.plot"

Any idea what the issue might be?

I do not really care much if I cannot use this function, but I'm curious as to what is going on in case I later need to use a graph that I really need.

Comment: Looks like the source code is available at [This Site](https://rdrr.io/rforge/mi/src/R/missing.pattern.plot.R)

Comment: seems that R cannot find the lm.mi function either, which is actually necessary to run my regressions on the multiply imputed data!

Comment: so I am guessing I should just paste that code in and it will install the function, which I did and it runs, but I am not seeing where the plot appears. I clicked on the plots tab and see nothing. also I searched in that website for the source code of lm.mi function and found nothing.

Comment: wait I found the source code for lm.mi and ran it, but then when I run the function I get this error:                                                                                                 > lm.mi.out <- lm.mi(y ~ x1 + x2, imp.mi)
Error in m(mi.object) : could not find function "m" (which is weird because I do not use function, not m)